# Why does not XSSFRichTextString.applyFont() work as it is written in java doc?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xssf

I am trying to apply bold font on parts of a string and place it in a cell.

```
XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
font.setBold(true);
XSSFCellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
style.setFont(font);
XSSFCell c = nextRow.createCell(4);
c.setCellStyle(style);
XSSFRichTextString string = new XSSFRichTextString(report.getSurroundText());
string.applyFont( startIndex, getEndOfWord(startIndex, report.getFoundWord()), font); 
c.setCellValue(string);
```

This code, as part of my code that produces an `.xlsx` file and it does produce a not corrupt file, but the text that should be bold is not correct. Instead it highlights from the start of the text to the index I set as end index in the `applyFont()` method. Basicly for some reason `startIndex` is ignored.

During debug, both `startIndex` and the return value of `getEndOfWord()` is correct.

EDIT:

```
try(FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(new File(directory.getAbsoluteFile() + File.separator + 
            FilenameUtils.getBaseName(csvFile.getAbsolutePath()) + ".xlsx"));) {
        try (XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook()) {
            XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Highlights");
            XSSFRow headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
            headerRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(firstLine);

            XSSFRow titleRow = sheet.createRow(1);
            titleRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(SCANID);
            titleRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(DOCID);
            titleRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(FOUNDWORD);
            titleRow.createCell(3).setCellValue(OFFSET);
            titleRow.createCell(4).setCellValue(SURROUNDTEXT);

            XSSFFont font = workbook.createFont();
            font.setBold(true);
            XSSFFont deFont = workbook.createFont();
            font.setBold(false);

            int row = 2;
            for (MuiDetailReport report : lst) {
                XSSFRow nextRow = sheet.createRow(row);
                nextRow.createCell(0).setCellValue(report.getScanId());
                nextRow.createCell(1).setCellValue(report.getDocId());
                nextRow.createCell(2).setCellValue(report.getFoundWord());
                if (report.getOffset() != 0) nextRow.createCell(3).setCellValue(report.getOffset());
                else nextRow.createCell(3).setCellValue("");
                if (!report.getFoundWord().isBlank() && !report.getSurroundText().isBlank()) {
                    int startIndex = getStartOfWord(report.getFoundWord(), report.getSurroundText());
                    if (startIndex == -1) nextRow.createCell(4).setCellValue("");
                    else {
                        XSSFCell c = nextRow.createCell(4);
                        XSSFRichTextString string = new XSSFRichTextString(report.getSurroundText());
                        string.applyFont(startIndex, getEndOfWord(startIndex, report.getFoundWord()), font);
                        c.setCellValue(string);
                    }
                } else nextRow.createCell(4).setCellValue("");
                row++;
            }
            workbook.write(fileOut);
        }
        fileOut.flush();
    }
```

This is my method for creating my `.xlsx` file. Method parameter: `String firstLine, List<MuiDetailReport> lst, File csvFile`. Variable with all uppercase characters are `static final String`

My result is "**Hellomyname**isThad" instead of "Hellomy**name**isThad"

Comment: I checked out your code on my system and it works as expected (with hard values set for the indexes). There is only one difference concerning the definition of the font, I used this `XSSFFont boldFont = new XSSFFont();` instead of `workbook.createFont();`. Maybe worth a try...

Comment: @deHaar how did that work for you? for me there is no available empty constructor for XSSFFont.

Comment: Oh, yes... I didn't overwrite that `XSSFRichTextString` with a cell style that uses the same font, sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinashnew The constructor XSSFFont() is not visible

Comment: @deHaar what do you mean by that???

Comment: You have applied a `CellStyle` with the same font to the cell (the entire one), which means that style will style all the text in the cell. Just don't do that and only set the `XSSFRichTextString` as cell value.

Comment: @deHaar it did not turn the whole cell into bold. Have you read my post? It turned everything before the index, getEndOfWord() returns, bold. When I try without that step nothing is bold.

Comment: Yes, I have read your post. The `CellStyle` applies to the entire cell and then gets overridden by the rich text conten, which doesn't care about the style of the text before the `startIndex`, but will style the remaining text as desired, which means it makes the desired part bold, no matter if it was bold before and makes the remaining text non bold.

Comment: @AxelRichter i will make an edit then.

Comment: @AxelRichter is this better? previously i had minimal code that clearly defined the parameters of my issue. The fact that i have issue with something simple does not make it not answerable, other people understood the problem, but for some reason they cant reproduce my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a really [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

The folowing should result in having the text

Hellomy**name**isThad

in Cell `A1`.

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

class CreateExcelBoldWord {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
  //Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();

  String fileName = (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook)?"Excel.xlsx":"Excel.xls";

  CreationHelper creationHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

  Font font = workbook.createFont(); // default font
  Font fontBold = workbook.createFont();
  fontBold.setBold(true);

  String text = "HellomynameisThad";
  String word = "name";

  RichTextString richTextString = creationHelper.createRichTextString(text);
  int startIndex = text.indexOf(word);
  int endIndex = startIndex + word.length();
  richTextString.applyFont(startIndex, endIndex, fontBold);

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
  sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue(richTextString);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }
}
```

No?

Comment: yes this example works, can you help me with figuring out what is the difference between this simple example and mine?

Comment: @Kristóf Horváth: How shall this be possible without knowing the whole context? Your code snippets both are not complete. And you claim your  `startIndex` is correct and `getEndOfWord` returns the correct end index. So if that is true there is not a differnence.

Comment: I have same setup except CreationHelper, but i tried that and still no luck

Comment: I use the same logic for end and start index as you.

Comment: context is super simple report.getSurroundText is your text and report.getFoundWord is your word

Comment: I think this had to do with my IDE acting up, I reset my IDE and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by **not applying a `CellStyle`** to the cell and just setting the `XSSFRichTextString` as the cell value.

See this example, which assumes an already created `XSSFWorkbook` and an `XSSFSheet`:

```
XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
XSSFFont boldFont = new XSSFFont();
boldFont.setBold(true);
XSSFRichTextString rts = new XSSFRichTextString("BVB BVB BVB");
rts.applyFont(4, 7, boldFont);
cell.setCellValue(rts);
```

I omitted the part that writes the workbook to the file system, I think yours is working already.

The result of this is a workbook with "BVB **BVB** BVB" in the first / upper left cell.

This is the part of my pom.xml (maven project) where apache poi dependencies are set, maybe you have an older version of it:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How the hell are you making new XSSFFont() work? It is not visible for me.

Comment: @KristófHorváth I don't know why it is working for me and not for you. Which version of apache poi are you using? See my edit, please... I have provided the versions I use.

Comment: I do not have last one, otherwise same

Comment: I added it to my pom and still nothing is bold

Comment: @KristófHorváth have you skipped setting the `CellStyle`, too?

Comment: yes i removed that part and the result is without any bold in it.

Comment: Still How the hell are you making new XSSFFont() work? For me its not visible.